# phpmyadmin autocomplete login info

Tags: phpmyadmin

is there a way to turn off the autocomplete=off feature? I can't seem to find that in index.php It's pretty stupid having to insert your login info every time

my pma version is: 4.1.6

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This directive,
http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_LoginCookieRecall

when set to true, will display the previous username used. Note that the blowfish_secret directive must be configured for this to work.